# How do I use metalsmith-permalinks in a Handlebars template

Tags: javascript, permalinks, handlebars.js, metalsmith

I have collections set up and working properly.

I am looping through a collection of projects

```
{{#each collections.projects}}
    <a href="" class="portfolio-entry">

        <div class="info-frame portfolio-title">
            <h4>{{this.title}}</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="info-bits centerContext">
            <ul class="centerElement">
                <li class="info-bit">{{this.skills}}</li>
                <li class="info-bit">{{this.type}}</li>
                <li class="info-bit">{{this.platform}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="project-thumbnail">
            <img src="{{this.thumbnail}}" alt="">
        </div>

    </a>
{{/each}}
```

I would like to use metalsmith-permalinks in order to resolve each link's url

I tried all kinds of lame things like this

```
<a href="{{this.permalink}}" class="portfolio-entry">
```

and this

```
<a href="{{this.url}}" class="portfolio-entry">
```

Of course - none of them works.

I struggled to find any detailed information on how to actually use permalinks within your template anywhere online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The permalinks plugin adds `path` metadata property that doesn't seem to be documented well. This should be what you need to achieve links.

The [Github page](https://github.com/segmentio/metalsmith-permalinks) notes:

> > If no pattern is provided, the files won't be remapped, but the `path` metadata key will still be set, so that you can use it for outputting links to files in the template.

I haven't found anywhere else showing the use of this but I'd assume the above quote means that it is standard behaviour.

You can use it like:

```
{{#each collections.projects}}
    <a href="/{{this.path}}/" class="portfolio-entry">
```

The first `/` is so that it resolves to the current host and the trailing `/` is optional (depending on your http server configuration.

Comment: That's exactly the solution I was looking for! Thank you very much James Khoury!

Comment: @jarodtaylor could you be more specific? It worked for the OP's simple example. Maybe you could make another question and show how your problem is different?